# How do I get video likes of my posted videos through facebook api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-insights

I am trying to get video-likes programmatically, the graph api requires a video-id, but I do not know how to get to the video-id?

Is there a way to get a list of all my posted video-ids?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can get the videos with the `/me/videos/uploaded` endpoint:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/videos

> /{user-id}/videos/uploaded shows all videos that were published to Facebook by this person.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, what I am really looking for is the "views" on my posted videos. It looks like, insights-api might be the way to go. I am trying to issue: /v2.2/<object-id>/insights/post_video_complete_views_organic, but I do not know how to correctly replace object-id with a correct page-id?

Comment: your question was about getting a list of the IDs and the likes. if you want to expand, please create a new thread for the additional question or edit your existing question.

Comment: OK, sure, I have created a new question. Thanks for the tip.